# mod_rewrite maintaining "changed URI"

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule that successfully redirects me to the appropriate page. The problem is that when I hover over a link on the redirected page, my URL for any link on this page has been altered as follows:

Correct link: http://www.mysitelcom/newClients.php

Link after RewriteRule: http://www.mysite.com/samples/article-title-goes-here/23/newClients.php  It has 'prefixed' the next file request with samples/article-title-goes-here/23/  which is the pattern part of my RewriteRule.

My .htaccess file is:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Do not do anything for already existing files and folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^sample/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ sample.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?  Somehow I have to 'reset' my URI so that it doesn't 'alter' the next requested filename.  Thank you for any thoughts.

Comment: This isn't a mod_rewrite issue. The only thing mod_rewrite does is change the way the web server handles a request. It can't edit your web pages on the fly - to change the links on the page, you need to edit the web page itself. If you have any code that generates the URLs on the web page, that's what you need to post.

Comment: I think I need to clarify...without my RewriteRule all my links behave as expected. My site is a simple PHP site. I altered the code to display friendly URLs as I described above. My RewriteRule correctly redirects to the appropriate page. My rewriteRule seems to be rewriting each link...when I hover over any link it has the friendly URL part inserted after the root as I showed above. Could it be that the mod_rewrite has changed/memorized the URI path. I feel I need to reset in some way. As I mentioned if I don't click on any of my friendly URLs I'm fine.

Comment: Again, that is not how mod_rewrite works. It cannot and will not affect the links shown on the page when you hover over them. You should look in your PHP code that generates the page - is it at any point using the URI from the current page to generate the links?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I found, that it's good solution for links and path in my engine always work correctly use such:

Global variables defined in my settings.php

```
<?php
    $path_server = 'htdocs/mysite';  # server path for including files
    $path_www = 'http://mysite.com'; # path to use in links
?>
```

So in my templates (they are in same scope as settings.php) I write

```
<?php include "{$path_server}/menu.php"; ?>
<a href='<?php echo $path_www; ?>/link1.html'>link1</a>
```